# IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> vs DbContext for Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, asp.net-identity

I am trying to build my IRepository interface and the concrete class EntityFrameworkGenericRepository, but I have a question on the DbContext.

In previous versions of MVC in your EFGenericRepository you would reference EntityFramework and use DbContext and that would be it.

Now that I am using MVC5 which has ASP.NET Identity, I need to switch out DbContext for IdentityDbContext but that means I will need to reference ASP.NET Identity.

Is there a way around this, or is this perfectly fine?

Snippet of constructor and properties

```
public class EntityFrameworkGenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T: class
{
    protected IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>Context = null;

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            return Context.Set<T>();
        }
    }


    public EntityFrameworkGenericRepository(IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        Context = context;
    }
```

And here is my WebAppDbContext :

```
public class WebAppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public WebAppDbContext()
        : base(nameOrConnectionString: "DefaultConnection") { }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that it does seem a bit odd to haveMicrosoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework as a dependency on the data layer which could be used by other non asp projects.

Answer (score -1):

This looks fine to me. Are there any specific concerns that you have?